EEVEE the object is black
I am using a laptop ASUS Vivobook S 15 with the following characteristics:

CPU - Snapdragon(R) X Elite - X1E78100 - Qualcomm(R) Oryon(TM) CPU
3.42 GHz;
Memory - 16 GB;
GPU - Snapdragon(R) X Elite - X1E78100 - Qualcomm(R) Adreno(TM);
Operating system - Windows 11, 64 bits, based on ARM.

When I choose the render engine EEVEE the object appears all black, if engine is Cycles everything is all right.
I have also read it could be a driver problem but I do not know how to solve this, the graphical board is last versions.
Can you give a clew  to resolve this problem.
Thanks for your time and cooperation.
Kind regards
Link for blend file:


Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry, I don't know why the cube is black, but I can tell you that it looks normal to me. Checked the viewport, Eevee, and Cycles of your file in Blender 4.2 (laptop). Everything is fine. It's probably a GPU / driver problem. Have you tried an older Blender version like 3.6 LTS?

I have installed a new version of blender(4.2.1 LTS) in an another computer with architecture X64 and problem persists. If the rendering is Cycles the cube appears in gray with shadows

try setting the render pass to combined in the top right corner, shading options in the 3d viewport

Thanks MohMehdi for your reply.
It was already set  the render pass to combined.
As I said before it seems to be a problem with build, if I use X64 it works fine...
My laptop is ARM architecture...

Navigate to Render > Performance, and ensure that High Quality Normals is checked.

Hello,
Yes High quality is checked
