my cube turns completely black when i enter viewport shading
when I enter the viewport shading window all the objects in my scene turn completely black. I have tried moving the light, repositioning the light, reloading the file, editing the shadow pool but nothing works.
if you need more info, please ask.
Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HKyiXTad2QT-wJSacovK43o8XGsHZV0m/view?usp=drive_link

can you upload the blend file?

same black cube here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/323188/107598, but no answer that solved it

I tried loading the file from the link mentioned by @Blunder and it worked fine.
so maybe the problem is this option in the image (render pass). set it to combined


it didn't work. i opened the file by @blunder and set it to the default "combined" setting but it is still not working

While I can't repeat the "Black cube" issue in Blender 4.2.0  or 4.2.1,  I came across this 3 minute video where the guy has what looks like the same issue you are experiencing.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKwdKUhyj4E

then I suggest trying a different version of Blender. try 3.X versions.
